# Ошибка во время миграции MySql.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Проект .net core, БД Mysql(MySql.EntityFrameworkCore).

Модель:

```
public class ProductInvoice
{
    public int IdInvoice { get; set; }
    public int IdProduct { get; set; }
    public int IdCell { get; set; }
    
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public WarehouseStreetLevelCell Cell { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
//Many to many Invoice vs Products
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInvoice>()
    .HasKey(p => new { p.IdInvoice, p.IdProduct, p.IdCell });

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInvoice>()
    .HasOne(ru => ru.Product)
    .WithMany(r => r.ProductInvoices)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.IdProduct);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInvoice>()
    .HasOne(pr => pr.Invoice)
    .WithMany(p => p.ProductInvoices)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.IdInvoice);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInvoice>()
    .HasOne(pr => pr.Cell)
    .WithMany(p => p.Invoices)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.IdCell);
```

Миграция:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
        name: "PK_ProductsInvoices",
        table: "ProductsInvoices");

    migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
        name: "PK_ProductsInvoices",
        table: "ProductsInvoices",
        columns: new[] { "IdInvoice", "IdProduct", "IdCell" });
}
```

Таблица пустая, данных в ней нет. Скрин структуры таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка при попытке сделать update:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `MYSQL_AFTER_ADD_PRIMARY_KEY`;
> CREATE PROCEDURE `MYSQL_AFTER_ADD_PRIMARY_KEY`(IN `SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT` VARCHAR(255), IN `TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT`
> VARCHAR(255), IN `COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT` VARCHAR(255))
> BEGIN
> DECLARE HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID INT(11);
> DECLARE PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(255);
> DECLARE PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE VARCHAR(255);
> DECLARE SQL_EXP VARCHAR(1000);
> SELECT COUNT(*)
> INTO HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID
> FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
> AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_NAME` = COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE '%int%'
> AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI';
> IF HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID THEN
> SELECT `COLUMN_TYPE`
> INTO PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE
> FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
> AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_NAME` = COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE '%int%'
> AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI';
> SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
> INTO PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME
> FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
> AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_NAME` = COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE '%int%'
> AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI';
> SET SQL_EXP = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA())), '`.`', TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT, '` MODIFY COLUMN `', PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME, '` ', PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE,
> ' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;');
> SET @SQL_EXP = SQL_EXP;
> PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE FROM @SQL_EXP;
> EXECUTE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE;
> END IF;
> END; Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
> `MYSQL_AFTER_ADD_PRIMARY_KEY`;   CREATE PROCEDURE
> `MYSQL_AFTER_ADD_PRIMARY_KEY`(IN `SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT` VARCHAR(255),
> IN `TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT` VARCHAR(255), IN `COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT`
> VARCHAR(255))   BEGIN
> DECLARE HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID INT(11);
> DECLARE PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(255);
> DECLARE PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE VARCHAR(255);
> DECLARE SQL_EXP VARCHAR(1000);
> SELECT COUNT(*)
> INTO HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID
> FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
> AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_NAME` = COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE '%int%'
> AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI';
> IF HAS_AUTO_INCREMENT_ID THEN
> SELECT `COLUMN_TYPE`
> INTO PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE
> FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
> AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_NAME` = COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE '%int%'
> AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI';
> SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
> INTO PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME
> FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA()))
> AND `TABLE_NAME` = TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_NAME` = COLUMN_NAME_ARGUMENT
> AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE '%int%'
> AND `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI';
> SET SQL_EXP = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', (SELECT IFNULL(SCHEMA_NAME_ARGUMENT, SCHEMA())), '`.`', TABLE_NAME_ARGUMENT, '` MODIFY COLUMN `', PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME, '` ', PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE,
> ' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;');
> SET @SQL_EXP = SQL_EXP;
> PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE FROM @SQL_EXP;
> EXECUTE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE SQL_EXP_EXECUTE;
> END IF;   END; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.  --->
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Parameter
> '@SQL_EXP' must be defined.    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection
> parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql,
> MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
> connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
> migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: Ну вроде вполне себе меняемое ошибалово. Ты используешь user-defined variable в `@SQL_EXP`, а доблестный фреймворк воспринимает начинающийся с символа `@` текст как параметр, вместо которого потом будет подставлено значения. А ты значения не подставил. Вот фреймворк и обиделся. С сообщением `Parameter '@SQL_EXP' must be defined.`

Comment: @Akina это все генерится автоматом где то под капотом MySql.EntityFrameworkCore я запрос не писал

Comment: Это понятно. Я просто стараюсь дать направление поиска. Вы не первый. И народ находил решения - но я не помню, ибо эта область мне неинтересна.